# How to replace and make anchor link in string using php

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string like

```
2 (75374, 722373, 717627)
```

I want to output string like

```
2 (<a href=''>75374</a>, <a href=''>722373</a>, <a href=''>717627</a>)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: i want to make the string inside ( ) as anchor tags.
2 ([75374](http://example.com), [722373](http://example.com), [717627](http://example.com))

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Also check how to write a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks moffeltje, for the editing and making the corrections in the question.

Makesh, i hope the questions is able to understand by you know. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: @VaseemAnsari CHECK ANSWER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace()`:-

```
<?php
    $string = '2 (75374, 722373, 717627)';
    echo preg_replace('/([0-9]{5,15})/',"<a href=''>$1</a>",$string);
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/400538

Note:- this will work only for number length from 5 to 15.Thanks

Comment: It worked AK. i was also hoping to get this done using preg_replace but i used some other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is array of srings,

```
$strings = array('75374', '722373', '717627');
```

Apply custom function to array values using `array_map()` to make it anchors,

```
$strings = array_map(function($value){
                return "<a href=''>{$value}</a>";
            }, $strings);
```

Comment: Viral, I have used the other way. I had a string rather than an array.